# Finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a certain matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix $A_{n\times n}$  where elements $a_{ij} $ of $A_{n\times n}$ are given as

\begin{cases}
\alpha,  & \text{if }i=j \\[2ex]
1, & \text{if }|i-j|=1\\[2ex]
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

where $\alpha$ is a constant.

I tried finding out the eigenvalues by finding the polynomial equation of this equation and the result which I was getting was of the form:-

$|A_{n\times n}-\lambda I_{n\times n}|=(\alpha-\lambda)(|A_{(n-1)\times (n-1)}-\lambda I_{(n-1)\times (n-1)}|-|A_{(n-2)\times (n-2)}-\lambda I_{(n-2)\times (n-2)}|)$

But I was not able to go further.

Comment: As has been posted on your previous questions, please keep in mind that askers are expected to provide some context to their questions. As the messages on your closed questions say: *please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.*

Comment: That said: in all seriousness, a reasonable amount context is important and is generally appreciated. For this problem, even saying something like "this is a problem I found while self-studying from textbook X" or "I computed the eigenvalues for the $2 \times 2$ case with $\alpha = 0$ but couldn't get much further" can be very helpful since it gives us an indication of the type and degree of guidance you might need.

Comment: I will surely take care of the comments from the next time. Will also edit this question a bit to set the progress that I made in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formula for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of such a matrix [is given here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal-Toeplitz-Matrix).

We can deduce these eigenvalues and eigenvectors nicely, however, if we correctly "guess" that we can find a complete set of eigenvectors in which each eigenvector is of the form
$$
v = (\sin(\theta), \sin(2 \theta), \dots , \sin (n \theta)).
$$
See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3527247/81360) for details on this approach.

Note that it suffices to consider the case of $\alpha = 0$, since for any matrix $M$, the matrices $M$ and $M + \alpha I$ have the same eigenvalues (where $I$ denotes the identity matrix).