# Eigenvalues of a tridiagonal matrix with $-1, 2, -1$ as entries

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices

This problem was given as an exercise for section 6.2 of Hoffman & Kunze's book in a course in linear algebra, which I couldn't solve and I really don't know how to solve it, may be because I don't know where does that $\sin^2$ come from.

Also I searched for it on the internet and results weren't close to this question and I tought may be it's wrong.

Anyway, this is the problem:

> If $$
> A = \begin{bmatrix}
> 2 & -1 \\
> -1 & 2 & -1 \\
> & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
> && -1 & 2 & -1 \\
> &&& -1 & 2 & -1 \\
> &&&& -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}
> $$
> and $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, then
> show eigenvalues of A are:
> $$4\sin^2 \left( \frac {j \pi}{2n+2}  \right)$$
> for $1\le j \le n$.

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: See Davide Giraudo's answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177957/eigenvalues-of-tridiagonal-symmetric-matrix-with-diagonal-entries-2-and-subdiago?rq=1

Comment: @v_lentin Thanks. But I'm not really happy with using recurrence relations. Do you know any other strategy to solve the problem?

Comment: @Masoud You might prefer the answer [given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3527247/81360) then